# I need to strip dynamic information from a html/php file with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, html, database, geolocation

I have been trying to strip information out of a dynamically generated page and then insert the information into a database, this is only a one time thing. to explain the layout:

I have a list of 700 IP addresses in my database currently but they have no location linked to them, I am using the following code to retrieve the information from hostip.info and insert the returned data into a variable on a loop:

```
dbconnect();
$tbl_name = 'Votes';
$sql = "SELECT * FROM $tbl_name LIMIT 10"; //THIS LIMIT IS ONLY A TEMPORARY //
$result=mysql_query($sql);  
$rows=mysql_fetch_array($result);
while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
     echo $rows['UIP']; //This is the IP stored currently
     $file_l = file_get_contents('http://api.hostip.info/get_html.php?ip='.$rows['UIP'].'&position=true');
}
```

For each IP tested the information returned from hostip.info looks a bit like this:

```
Country: UNITED KINGDOM (GB)
City: (Unknown city)
Latitude: 
Longitude: 
IP: 79.170.40.245
```

just in plain text, I basically want to grab the Lat, Long and City from it and whack it in a database, HOWEVER, the city, lat and long are all different lengths. Is there any way to strip this information with maybe preg_match or something like that, I have tried but Can't figure it out. Any ideas greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You should use this URL instead :

```
http://api.hostip.info/?ip=$rows['UIP']
```

It returns XML which is easier to parse. You can even do it in AJAX this way \o/

[Source](http://www.hostip.info/use.html)

Comment: I am such a massive spastic. Cheers. I should've thought of trying the XML.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$str="Country: UNITED KINGDOM (GB) City: (Unknown city) Latitude: Longitude: IP: 79.170.40.245";
$arr=explode(" ",$str);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($arr);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to bother with an XML parser for something so simple.

```
while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
{
    echo $rows['UIP']; //This is the IP stored currently
    $file_l = file_get_contents('http://api.hostip.info/get_html.php?ip='.$rows['UIP'].'&position=true');

    $lines = explode("\n", $file_l);
    $values = array();
    foreach($lines as $line)
    {
        $s = explode(':', $line);
        $values[$s[0]] = trim($s[1]);
    }
    doSomethingWith($values['City'], $values['Latitude'], $values['Longitude']);
}
```

Comment: Awesome, that's exactly what I needed, cheers for all of your input